# Where can I get the source of packages start with `sun` in JDK?

Tags: java, nio, sun

I'm learning java nio, and found the implementation classes are under `sun.nio`, which seems not provide sources in the `jdk1.6/src.zip`.

Is there packages open source? And where to find the sources of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the java code and native code which implements java.nio at http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/ (see top_dir/j2se/src/share/classes/java/nio/ after extracting the source zip)

Please note that you will be able to see the platform dependent code like the code for Solaris, Linux and Windows as well in this.

Answer (score 0):

It's available under the Community Source Licence somewhere, but you would he better off getting to know the Berkeley Sockets API on which it is based.